# SQL Server 2008 Import/Export data

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL Server and not very well-versed in how things run with it.  Can anyone point me to what exactly this error means? https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C9TQ.jpg
It happens when I try to select a database name when importing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occuring because you can't connect to the instance.  Check your connection string and ensure that your parameters are correct:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress\NamedInstance;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Use your connection string parameters to manually connect to the instance through SSMS.  That'll give you a good indication that it is right/wrong.

Comment: how does one manually connect to the instance through SSMS? :) will accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: I can connect to analysis services with management studio, but I can't connect to the Database engine.  That's when I get that error.  Any idea on what's happening there?

Comment: @DarrinCecil Is your SQL Server service started??  Run Configuration Manager (run -> sqlservermanager10.msc if you are using SQL Server 2008) to see the status of the service(s).